# Customize push notification position in GNOME

Tags: configuration, notification, gnome-shell

How do I change the position of the push notifications? I'm currently running Ubuntu 17.10 but I couldn't find anything in my settings nor online about changing such settings.

I would be very happy to be able to change the position because it's often on top of areas where I want to click or type. A more ideal position for my case would be on the right bottom of the screen. Currently it's position at the center top, have a look at the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of push notification]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[Panel OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/)" to achieve your goal.

This extension lets you configure the position of the notification pop-up.

[image]

Comment: Works great for me; Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this work for Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: This has been abandoned by the original author. Notification banner reloaded worked for me on 22.04.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Notification Banner Reloaded](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4651/notification-banner-reloaded/) addon instead if you're running Ubuntu 21.10 or later. This extension is more advanced and allows you a larger range of notification location options, including top, middle, or bottom, as well as left or right.

[image]

[**Credit**](https://149366088.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/notification.gif).

Comment: That's the one, Panel OSD had been abandoned by its original maintainer. This one works just perfect.